# Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use pretrained embeddings as a layer in a neural network but can't quite get it to work. The error I am getting is in the reshape layer:

```
Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
epochs = 50

n_units = 512
embedding_size = 200

text_in = Input(shape = ())
embedding_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/3")(text_in)
reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(None, 1024, 1))(embedding_layer)
x = LSTM(n_units)(reshape)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
text_out = Dense(total_words, activation = 'softmax')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=output_layer, name="LSTM with ELMo Embeddings")

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'None' should not be there. Keras is bit weird and it often treats the first dimension as something special. In this case, the first (batch size) dimension is omitted and the layer can't change it.

Otherwise, your code has probably more issues. `input_layer` and `output_layer` are not defined. Shape (?, 1024, 1) is weird. You have sequences of length 1024 and only 1D embeddings? The whole code looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/reshape/ `None` is not support for unknown dimension size with `keras.layers.Reshape`. However you can use `-1` instead and it should works as you want

PS: don't forget to change `input_layer`/`output_layer` (in `keras.Model`) by `text_in`/`text_out` (you don't need to put `input_layer` in a list btw)